# PHP MP3 JSON Waveform data for Android to Generate image of Waveform

Tags: php, android, json, git, waveform

I need to build a web script that converts a mp3 file to a waveform data in json format which can be usable by android developers to generate waveform image with this data.

For generating waveform data in php, I used this git repo => https://github.com/alexkirs/php-waveform-json and **it works fine**.

**Now the problem is waveform data generate from php is not suitable for android. So, how to generate waveform data in php that can be use in android to generate waveform?**

To elaborate,
I used one sample mp3 file for generate waveform data in php as json and received output as below,

```
{
    "left": [0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.0176, 0.002, 0.0216, 0.002, 0.0255, 0.002, 0.0255, 0.002]
}
```

that mean all positive, which throws error from android side to generate waveform. However for the same samle mp3 file I generated waveform from online tool and recieved data as below which is working perfectly on android to generate. That data form as 1st either zero or negative and second zero and positive and so on.
Below data generated via online tool and works for android.

```
{
    "data": [0, 3, 0, 3, -1, 6, -8, 11, -23, 26, -26, 24, -29, 21, -32, 25, -30, 24, -25, 23, -28, 26, -30, 30, -32, 31]
}
```

---

**Could anybody tell me how to generate waveform in php which can be works on android? or any alternative solution?**

---

The following is the php code as is (also available [in this repository on GitHub](https://github.com/alexkirs/php-waveform-json)).

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_error', false);
ini_set("max_execution_time", "30000");

$file = "test.mp3";
$flat = "on";


// how much detail we want. Larger number means less detail
// (basically, how many bytes/frames to skip processing)
// the lower the number means longer processing time
define("DETAIL", 5);

if (file_exists($file)) {

    /**
     * PROCESS THE FILE
     */
    // temporary file name
    $tmpname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "wav2json_");

    // copy from temp upload directory to current
    copy($file, "{$tmpname}_o.mp3");

    // support for stereo waveform?
    $stereo = false;
//    $stereo = true;
    // array of wavs that need to be processed
    $wavs_to_process = array();

    /**
     * convert mp3 to wav using lame decoder
     * First, resample the original mp3 using as mono (-m m), 16 bit (-b 16), and 8 KHz (--resample 8)
     * Secondly, convert that resampled mp3 into a wav
     * We don't necessarily need high quality audio to produce a waveform, doing this process reduces the WAV
     * to it's simplest form and makes processing significantly faster
     */
    if ($stereo) {
        // scale right channel down (a scale of 0 does not work)
        exec("lame {$tmpname}_o.mp3 --scale-r 0.1 -m m -S -f -b 16 --resample 8 {$tmpname}.mp3 && lame -S --decode {$tmpname}.mp3 {$tmpname}_l.wav");
        // same as above, left channel
        exec("lame {$tmpname}_o.mp3 --scale-l 0.1 -m m -S -f -b 16 --resample 8 {$tmpname}.mp3 && lame -S --decode {$tmpname}.mp3 {$tmpname}_r.wav");
        $wavs_to_process[] = "{$tmpname}_l.wav";
        $wavs_to_process[] = "{$tmpname}_r.wav";
    } else {
        exec("lame {$tmpname}_o.mp3 -m m -S -f -b 16 --resample 8 {$tmpname}.mp3 && lame -S --decode {$tmpname}.mp3 {$tmpname}.wav");
        $wavs_to_process[] = "{$tmpname}.wav";
    }
    // delete temporary files
    unlink("{$tmpname}_o.mp3");
    unlink("{$tmpname}.mp3");
    unlink("{$tmpname}");

    // get user vars from form
    $draw_flat = (isset($flat) && $flat == "on") ? true : false;

    $json = new stdclass;

    // process each wav individually
    for ($wav = 1; $wav <= sizeof($wavs_to_process); $wav++) {

        $filename = $wavs_to_process[$wav - 1];

        if ($wav == 1) {
            $json->left = array();
            $array = & $json->left;
        } else {
            $json->right = array();
            $array = & $json->right;
        }

        /**
         * Below as posted by "zvoneM" on
         * http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/reading-16-bit-wav-file-318740.html
         * as findValues() defined above
         * Translated from Croation to English - July 11, 2011
         */
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        // wav file header retrieval
        $heading[] = fread($handle, 4);
        $heading[] = bin2hex(fread($handle, 4));
        $heading[] = fread($handle, 4);
        $heading[] = fread($handle, 4);
        $heading[] = bin2hex(fread($handle, 4));
        $heading[] = bin2hex(fread($handle, 2));
        $heading[] = bin2hex(fread($handle, 2));
        $heading[] = bin2hex(fread($handle, 4));
        $heading[] = bin2hex(fread($handle, 4));
        $heading[] = bin2hex(fread($handle, 2));
        $heading[] = bin2hex(fread($handle, 2));
        $heading[] = fread($handle, 4);
        $heading[] = bin2hex(fread($handle, 4));

        // wav bitrate 
        $peek = hexdec(substr($heading[10], 0, 2));

        $byte = $peek / 8;

        // checking whether a mono or stereo wav
        $channel = hexdec(substr($heading[6], 0, 2));

        $ratio = ($channel == 2 ? 40 : 80);

        // start putting together the initial canvas
        // $data_size = (size_of_file - header_bytes_read) / skipped_bytes + 1
        $data_size = floor((filesize($filename) - 44) / ($ratio + $byte) + 1);
        $data_point = 0;


        while (!feof($handle) && $data_point < $data_size) {
            if ($data_point++ % DETAIL == 0) {
                $bytes = array();

                // get number of bytes depending on bitrate
                for ($i = 0; $i < $byte; $i++)
                    $bytes[$i] = fgetc($handle);

                switch ($byte) {
                    // get value for 8-bit wav
                    case 1:
                        $data = findValues($bytes[0], $bytes[1]);
                        break;
                    // get value for 16-bit wav
                    case 2:
                        if (ord($bytes[1]) & 128)
                            $temp = 0;
                        else
                            $temp = 128;

                        $temp = chr((ord($bytes[1]) & 127) + $temp);
                        $data = floor(findValues($bytes[0], $temp) / 256);
                        break;
                }

                // skip bytes for memory optimization
                fseek($handle, $ratio, SEEK_CUR);

                // draw this data point
                // relative value based on height of image being generated
                // data values can range between 0 and 255
                $v = ($data / 255);
                $array[] = (float) number_format(abs(0.5 - $v), 4);
            } else {
                // skip this one due to lack of detail
                fseek($handle, $ratio + $byte, SEEK_CUR);
            }
        }

        // close and cleanup
        fclose($handle);

        // delete the processed wav file
        unlink($filename);
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/json");


    echo json_encode($json);
} else {
    "Please select file";
}

/**
 * GENERAL FUNCTIONS
 */
function findValues($byte1, $byte2) {
    $byte1 = hexdec(bin2hex($byte1));
    $byte2 = hexdec(bin2hex($byte2));

    return ($byte1 + ($byte2 * 256));
}
```